# break does not stop the for loop

Tags: java, android, foreach

I have a problem with my code and I want to find a match in Firebase, delete the item and stop looking for the match, but it does not and what happens is that it deletes all the elements

```
for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Product product = dataSnapshot2.getValue(Product.class);
    String product_name = producto.getNombre();
    String key = dataSnapshot2.getKey();

    if(spinner_product.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(product_name)) {
        bbdd.child(key).removeValue();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: first check weather it is going inside the if statement or not. I am sure that it is not going inside it.

Comment: Add a breakpoint inside the for loop

Comment: Or he has some kind of outer loop going on.

Comment: @RanjanDas sorry, weather?

Comment: There is no sufficient information to answer this question. Add more details about the code, e.g. what is `bbdd` or maybe there is other parts of code that affect the result

Comment: Have you done debugging ?

Comment: put a log inside the if statement and check, it is visible or not.

Comment: BBDD is Database Reference of Firebase Database, sorry

Answer (score 0):

**Edit : as @Rafal said, instanciate the boolean outside the loop is obviously better !**

Never use `break` as it is very unstable.

You can try this even if a `do{}while();` loop is better :

Instanciate a boolean :

```
Boolean flag = false;
for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Product product = dataSnapshot2.getValue(Product.class);
    String product_name = producto.getNombre();
    String key = dataSnapshot2.getKey();

    if(flag == false && spinner_product.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(product_name)) {
        bbdd.child(key).removeValue();
        flag=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the answer of @Lozenzo, but declaring a flag inside a loop isn't the best solution and notice that the loop isn't going to stop until it checks all the elements in dataSnapshot.getChildren()!

Try declaring flag before the loop and adding it to loop condition. You may find do while loop type useful for this task.